# Code-first approach - connection string to generate the database in SQL Server Express [Windows Authentication]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first, connection-string

I'm trying to define a connection string for EF code-first approach to generate the database in SQL Server Express.

I'm logging into my pc using `/user` account, once I put following connection string in `web.config` file in my WebAPI project

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="libraryappconnectionstring" 
         connectionString="Data Source=minchiepad\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LibraryAppDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I can see its listing under server explorer tab

[image]

When I try to connect I'm getting following error

[image]

Once I googled, all the related answer for this errors are for existing DBs

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Where should I configure to fix that error connection string or SQL Server? And how?

Comment: Is minchiepad the name of your development computer (where you are running the code from) or is it a remote server?

Comment: minchiepad is the name of my development computer

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibility is user don't have access to the DB you attempting to access.

Check these settings.

[image]

Try changing the Default Database to LibraryAppDB in General Properties

I can see Space in the username at first, does local user has same name. Check is that causing any issue by any means.

Check "user mapping" to know the DB access allowed to this user.

Comment: Yeah this one same

Comment: I have refer here user properties not the DB properties, in general setting its showing login users name, cannot setup user mapping since DB not generated yet